# Sending message to other class via Selector

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, selector

I'm building a MacOS app that has a NSMenu.

Problem is I'm trying to send the `action` message to a class function in `MenuEventHandler` while there is no `target` I can specify. And the following `#selector(MenuEventHandler.sayHi)` doesn't work. The menu item would gray out.

```
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Option0", action: #selector(MenuEventHandler.sayHi), keyEquivalent: "n"))
```

```
class MenuEventHandler {

    @objc static func sayHi(){
        print("Hi")
    }
}
```

However, the strange things is, the similar syntax works for `quit`.

```
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
```

What's the correct syntax for sending the message to other class via `selector`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The class must be a subclass of `NSObject` and must be in the responder chain.

Comment: Why can't you specify the target?

Answer (score -1):

```
import Cocoa

class MenuEventHandler {
 @objc func sayHi(){
   NSSound.beep()
   print("Hi")
  }
}

let menuEventHandler = MenuEventHandler()

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var window:NSWindow!

func buildMenu() {
 let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 let optionMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Option0", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "n")
 optionMenuItem.target = menuEventHandler
 optionMenuItem.action = #selector(menuEventHandler.sayHi)
 appMenu.addItem(optionMenuItem) 
 appMenu.addItem(.separator())
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
}

func buildWnd() {    
let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
let _wndH : CGFloat = 300

 window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** Main **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.delegate = appDelegate
application.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Comment: To whoever docked my answer two points please explain why.  It is a perfectly good solution which answers the problem.